# How to change Font color for disabled TComboBox?

Tags: delphi, fonts, combobox, controls, delphi-xe2

I have a `TComboBox` with `Style:= csOwnerDrawVariable;` and I want to show the disabled `Font` color in black and not in 'gray'.

This is what I get with this source:

```
procedure TCustomComboBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    CN_CTLCOLORMSGBOX .. CN_CTLCOLORSTATIC, //48434..48440
    WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX .. WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    begin
      Color:= GetBackgroundColor; // get's the current background state
      Brush.Color:= Color;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

[image]

But I want the Font color of the inner `Edit` control in black.

If I change `Font.Color:= clBlack` at the `WndProc` or something else nothing happens.

A Google search give me some tips about changing a `TEdit` as read only, but this doesn't help me yet.

**Update**

Here is now my short solution after getting the tip from @Abelisto.

```
TCustomComboBox = class (TComboBox)
protected
  procedure DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState); override;
end;

procedure TCustomComboBox.DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  if odComboBoxEdit in State then begin // If we are drawing item in the edit part of the Combo
    if not Enabled then
      Canvas.Font.Color:= clBlack; // Disabled font colors
    Canvas.Brush.Color:= GetBackgroundColor; // Get the right background color: normal, mandatory or disabled
  end;
  inherited DrawItem(Index, Rect, State);
end;
```

Comment: where do u change the Font.Color ? In the WndProc or somewhere else ?

Comment: @GuidoG yeah tried WndProc too, but can't change the font of the edit control.

Comment: not sure if it works, but in wndprod the brush is for background and Pen is for foreground. Try changing the pen.color

Comment: Then `SetTextColor`, but note that the `inherited` call turns it back.

Comment: @GuidoG thx for the tipp, but it doesn't work

Comment: @TLama thx for the tipp, but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for silly questin but... did you try to use `OnDrawItem` event? Or to override `DrawItem` method?

Comment: @Abelisto OnDrawItem doesn't works with csOwnerDrawVariable, and I can't use csOwnerDraw in this case.

Comment: Strange. I just check it exactly for `Style := csOwnerDrawVariable;` and `OnDrawItem` works fine. However i tried it on D2007.

Comment: @Abelisto ok i'll this try again, but notice, i don't want to change the items in the list, i want to change the selected item.

Comment: `if odComboBoxEdit in State` - the edit field of the combo. Just checked on the D XE7 - works fine too.

Comment: @Abelisto it would be nice if can post a working answer with some source :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `OnDrawItem` event.
There is no special settings for the components at design time - all performed in code. Just put on the form ComboBox1 and Button1 and assign the events to them.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Enabled := not ComboBox1.Enabled; // Change Enabled state
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  txt: string;
begin
  if Index > -1 then
    txt := ComboBox1.Items[Index]
  else
    txt := '';
  if odComboBoxEdit in State then // If we are drawing item in the edit part of the Combo
    if ComboBox1.Enabled then
    begin // Enabled colors
      ComboBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed; // Foreground
      ComboBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWindow; // Background
    end
    else
    begin // Disabled colors
      ComboBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clYellow;
      ComboBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGray;
    end;

  ComboBox1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, txt); // Draw item. It may be more complex 
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ComboBox1 do // Setup combo props
  begin
    Items.Add('111');
    Items.Add('222');
    Items.Add('333');
    ItemIndex := 1;
    Style := csOwnerDrawVariable;
  end;
end;
```